# NotificationCompat.Builder is creating notifications that are canceled after one notification is selected

Tags: android, notifications, crosswalk-runtime

My app generates notifications like so :

```
final Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
final String title = intentExtras.getString(Constants.EXTRA_TITLE);
final String body = intentExtras.getString(Constants.EXTRA_BODY);
final Integer notifID = intentExtras.getInt(Constants.EXTRA_ID);

// this pending intent will launch after notification is selected
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtras(intentExtras);// pass the extra data forward to NotificationReceiverActivity
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notifID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

// build notification to show on the notification bar
try
{
    final String packagename = context.getPackageName();
    PackageInfo packageinfo = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packagename, 0);
    final int iconid = packageinfo.applicationInfo.icon;

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(iconid)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body);

    // build notification and set alerts
    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

    // show notification
    NotificationManager notificationMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationMgr.notify(notifID, notification);
}
catch (android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
{}
```

each `notifID` is unique ! However, if the app is showing two or more notifications, and the user selects one of them, both notifications for the app are cleared !

I have tried using `setAutoCancel(false)` or `setAutoCancel(true)` but it doesn't make a difference.

Additionally, there are no calls to `NotificationManager.cancel()` or `NotificationManager.cancelAll()`

How can I prevent the app from clearing all notifications for the app after a user has selected just one of them ?

**FURTHER INVESTIGATION...**

I've found that the notifications for the app disappear after I launch the app.
However, no .cancel() or .cancelAll() in sight... /confused

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Crosswalk (XWalkView) took the liberty of .cancelAll() notifications !!!
/facepalm x 100000

https://github.com/wuhengzhi/crosswalk/commit/32205e256dbb35ee70c895de4fe7c76d165b30dd